# What is a good reference for Bayesian time series and/(or separately) spatial statistics at a graduate level?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, references, spatial

(as title)
I am currently looking at Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models by Harrison and West. Is this text (published 1989) still relevant in that the fundamentals or core principals have not expanded beyond the text's coverage? A quick glance at its introduction and toc suggests it's still relevant; however, i have little to no background in time series to say for sure.